# PHP upload MAX_FILE_SIZE error 2

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to use Zend file transfer to upload a file

in php.ini I set:

**upload_max_filesize = 20M**

**post_max_size = 20M**

when I try to upload a 1MB file I get **error 2** complaining about max_file_size

I tried setting MAX_FILE_SIZE  in html as well

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152000000" />
```

but nothing is working

**PHP Variables of the Upload request:**

```
_REQUEST["MAX_FILE_SIZE"]  2097152000000

_REQUEST["PHPSESSID"]   b866b7105cb4747497f8744f56a807a0

_POST["MAX_FILE_SIZE"]  2097152000000

_FILES["userfile"]  

Array
(
    [name] => 1mpImage.jpg
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => 
    [error] => 2
    [size] => 
)
```

any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct php.ini file? Have you restarted your web server since changing the value? (Check the output of `phpinfo();` to be sure.)

Comment: According to php.net it is a problem with the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in the form -> http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php and http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php#74693

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up now and again and usually the answer is:

> In order for the ini changes to become active your apache server would need to be restarted.

If your on windows then run

```
apache -k restart
```

alternatively you can just open up `services.msc` > find apache web server nad right click restart.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with ini changes

Comment: OP said 'in php.ini I set:' so yes, it does.

Comment: @dogmatic69 you don't inderstand what he says

Comment: @RobertPitt yes, I did restart apache(sorry for not mentioning that)! but still it is not working... phpinof() shows: file_uploads On, upload_max_filesize 20M, post_max_size 20M..

Comment: the error 2 is directly related to the field you sticking in the form. why is that number so big? like 2TB...

Comment: Why the downvote, If the OP had his original settings at `512K` and them changed to `2M` without restart his upload would as it will exceed the max file size ?

Comment: I have explained earlier in comments. His error has nothing to do with php.ini. You can't read.

Comment: neither can you, he said that he tried setting `MAX_FILE_SIZE` **after** he had had got the error, thus removing the html element will not make a difference !!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use that input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152000000" />
```

And you should have

```
<input type="file" value="">
```

Value="" that's the point